# How to unwrap a discriminated union without pattern matching?

Tags: f#

I have a discriminated union like this:

```
Type Result =
| Good of bool | Bad of bool
```

In many cases I know that result is Good. To unwrap the Result, I have to use pattern matching for just the Good option. As a result I get a warning (not an error) that says "Incomplete pattern match on this expression..". Is there a way to unwrap is without having to use pattern matching?

Comment: If, in many cases, you know that the result is `Good` I'd reconsider the design instead of 'casting' to `Good` all the time.

Comment: Another way to put it: if the result is always `Good` and never `Bad`, why return a type that could be either? Just return whatever value is wrapped by Good directly. The top-rated answer suggests introducing potential run-time failures and that's really a last-resort option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add methods to unions just like any other type, like this:

```
type Result =
    | Good of bool
    | Bad of bool
    with
        member x.GoodValue =
            match x with
            | Good b -> b
            | Bad _ -> failwith "Not a good value"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let r = Good true
    let s = Bad true

    printfn "%A" r.GoodValue
    printfn "%A" s.GoodValue // You know what happens..!

    0
```

Answer (score 11):

You can just use `let`, e.g.

```
type Result =
    | Good of bool 
    | Bad of bool

let example = Good true

let (Good unwrappedBool) = example
```

Note that this will still result in a compiler warning that the match cases might be incomplete.

Technically, however, this is still *using pattern matching*, just doing so without a `match` expression.